# Смена значений innerhtml

Tags: javascript

На странице есть span `<span id="chart_title">Cur</span>` Как сделать так, чтобы ему присваивались значения переменной, даже если переменная меняет свое значение? Т.е динамически это сделать.
Пробовал так `document.getElementById("chart_title").innerHTML= CoinVal;` Но значение присваивается только при загрузке страницы, и даже если оно меняется потом, то в span оно не подтягивается

Comment: менять значение сразу после изменения значения переменной, то есть после каждой строчки `CoinVal=...` писать `document.getElementById("chart_title").innerHTML= CoinVal;`

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать функцию

```
const setChartTitle = (value) => {
  const el = document.getElementById("chart_title");
  if (el) {
     el.innerHTML = value;
  }
}
```

И изменять значение через функцию.

```
setChartTitle(CoinVal);
```

Если нету доступа к CoinVal, можно добавить таймер, каждые 10-100мс вызывать функцию `setChartTitle(CoinVal);`

Comment: А еще можно написать свой observer
https://abdulapopoola.com/2015/04/17/how-to-watch-variables-in-javascript/